# How can I download a list of Bigquery users?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

Is there a way to download the list of BigQuery users to audit?
There is no export option in BQ's IAM page for members.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Searching Cloud IAM policies option, which allows you to use a custom query language to search Cloud Identity and Access Management (Cloud IAM) policies within a project, folder or organization. Before using, we have to enable the `Cloud Asset API` for your project and grant the `cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies` permission to the user account or service account that is making the request.

Following command will show you the users who are granted with BigQuery roles on the specified project:

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=projects/<PROJECT_ID> --query="policy : bigquery" | egrep "role:|user:"
```

Moreover, you can save the result of a query to the file by adding `> <FILENAME>.txt` at the end of above command. To gain more knowledge about this command, please, refer to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies#how_to_construct_a_query).

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.